# jquery edit post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a edit post using jquery. But my code doesn't worked.
It need to work when i click the edit button then the `editMarkUp` wil be put in `messageB1` but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me here what i am missing and what is the solution?

This is **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/33mjrf1g/2/)** from *jsfiddle.net*

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html();
        var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea><button name="ok" ">Save</button><button name="cancel">Cancel</button>';
        $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
      <div class="postInfo">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsa
      </div>
      <div class="editBtn" id="1">Edit</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `Uncaught ReferenceError: editobj is not defined` in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not defining `editobj` variable anywhere in your code, and I guess you probably meant `.postInfo` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.postInfo').prop('disabled', 'true');
    var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea><button name="ok" ">Save</button><button name="cancel">Cancel</button>';
    $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
  });
});
```

**[MODIFIED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/33mjrf1g/3/)**

Comment: thank you. I am sorry for this question i am learning :) . Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. While you test your code, you got great tool in browser's Web Developer Tools at your disposal, learn **[how to use it](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)** ;)